How do I download the SDK when installing Android Studio on M3?
When I download Android Studio on Macbook M3, it does not download the SDK. When I download Android Studio, it does not allow me to download SDK. sdk (unavailable) appears and I cannot select it What should I do? I have been struggling with this for weeks, please help.
I tried to download and integrate it manually, but i did not work.

Please post the exact error message you get.


Open your project.
From the top menu, select Android Studio.
Click on Settings.
Navigate to Languages & Frameworks > Android SDK.
Edit the Android SDK Location and choose a suitable directory.

If you see a list of SDKs, you can proceed to download them. If not, there may be an issue with your internet connection. Are you using a proxy or VPN?

As far as I understand the question the problem is that the whole Android SDK can not be downloaded, therefore there is no SDK installed you could point AS to.
